# Difference between First order Lagrange and second order Lagrange in Optimisation?

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, lagrange-multiplier, non-convex-optimization

So, I'm studying maths in French and in my notes there is what's called a second order Lagrange that has these following conditions ( I couldn't find the equivalent in the internet so I'm translating them and hopefully I get them right ) :

let $x* \in A:=${$x \in \Omega : g_j(x)=_j , j=1,..,m$} be a local solution and let's suppose that :

1/ $f$ is two times differentiable in $x^*$.

2/ $g$ is of class $C^2$

3/ the family $\nabla g_1(x^*),...,\nabla g_m(x^*)$ is lineary independent

then there exists $\lambda:=(\lambda_1,..,\lambda_m) \in \Bbb R^m$ such that :

$\nabla_x L(x^*,\lambda) = \nabla f(x^*) - \sum_{j=1} ^m \lambda _j \nabla g_j(x^*)=0$  and $\partial _{xx}^2L(x^*,\lambda)(h,h) \ge  0$ for every $h \in ker(g'(x^*))$

What I don't get is :

why do we need the second order, it doesn't feel much different than the first order except for the positive second partial derivative?What am I missing here?

( Also, what's the equivalent of this theorem in English because I couldn't find it )

Comment: It's kind of like how, in calculus, you find critical points by setting the derivative equal to $0$ ( a first-order optimality condition), but you look at the second derivative to classify critical points as local minima or local maxima.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are Karush–Kuhn–Tucker conditions. First order condition is necessary. It includes saddle points.

Second order conditions are sufficient. They make sure your solution is actually a local minimum. The term $h \in ker(g'(x^*))$ means that you test the second order directional derivative only in directions that satisfy constraints.